# I am trying to download whole page as PDF using JSPDF, However Text in generated PDF file goes out of the page

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Here is my code, I am trying to download a div named PDFContent which contains number of images and Texts. Images gets fit into PDF generated file, but Text does not.

$("#downloadManual").click(function() {
            console.log("WOrking on PDF generation")

```
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        //var pdf = new jsPDF();

        source = $('#PDFContent').html();

        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme' : function(element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };

        margins = {
            top : 5,
            bottom : 60,
            left : 10,
            width : 700
        };

        pdf.fromHTML(source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width' : margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers' : specialElementHandlers
        },

        function(dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            headerFooterFormatting(pdf, pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages());
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, margins);

    });//end of button click event
```

Comment: Take into account that the resulted PDF File will not get the css that you had in your HTML Code, so if you have some css for give style to the text such as positioning, etc, it is probably that you won't get the same result in your PDF.

Comment: I tried adding with to div that I am trying to download, <div id="PDFContent" style="width: 400px">. Still I am unable to get the text.

Comment: Ok, I think I get you, Have you tried to use $('#PDFContent').outerHTML() instead of $('#PDFContent').html(), because html() will give you the innerHTML instead of the whole HTML element.

Comment: @BrankVictoria, I was unable to generate a PDF File after I used outerHTML.

Comment: If you used html() with just text isn't not working for you either?

Comment: @BrankVictoria when I only use content.html(), the pdf gets generated. But when i used content.outerHTML, the pdf does not generated neither any errors occurs.